# Visual Studio Code disappears folding controls

Tags: visual-studio-code

On launch the folding controls show and behave as expected, a few seconds later the controls are gone, I've tried various configurations and reinstalling and it doesn't fix it.

This only happens on one of my machines, on the other I don't have this problem, and although the "Settings sync is on" option on both machines, only on one of them do I have this problema.

[Look at this video](https://youtu.be/rSVuIfP2KJ0)

Settings JSON:

```
"editor.showFoldingControls": "always"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Does this happen to you in any other language modes other than PHP? 2) Does this happen when you run with all default settings other than the one you have shown? 3) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Will try disabling extensions. Thanks!

Comment: It was an extensión, see answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code for a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled** on the command pallete I was able to find that the extensión:

*#region folding for VS Code*

was causing the folding controls to disappear.